# adbコマンドによるユーザビリティの設定変更

Tags: android, adb

adbコマンドでユーザビリティの設定変更をする方法がわかりません。

特に、talkbackやSelect to Speakをなどの音声出力に関する設定をONに切り替える方法はないでしょうか?